# jboss deployment error spring hibernate maven

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am tring to deploy an application to jBoss 4.2.3
I think I have missed something in jboss configuration.
What i have made. I download jboss 4.2.3, place tuxgrh-ws-1.0.x.war in 
"jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy" folder and launch run.bat in a console. I have a mysql server with a database.

I get next errors in jboss console:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [spring/tuxgrh-applicationContext-jpa.xml]: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'tuxgrhDataSource' while setting bean
>   property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tuxgrhDataSource': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   TuxGRHDS not bound
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tuxgrhDataSource': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   TuxGRHDS not bound
>
> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TuxGRHDS not bound

[Full text of error log](http://justpaste.it/jr5n)

tuxgrhDataSource is refered in next files

tuxgrh-ds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>TuxGRHDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_tuxgrh</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class> 
        <user-name>newuser</user-name>
        <password>newuser</password>
        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>3</max-pool-size>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

and in tuxgrh-applicationContext-jpa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.tritux.tuxgrh.logic.repository" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="tuxgrhDataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
                p:database="MYSQL" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />   
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tritux.tuxgrh.logic.model"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="tuxgrhDataSource" jndi-name="java:/TuxGRHDS" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a JNDI JDBC datasource by the name "TuxGRHDS" on the server?

Comment: I put mysql-ds.xml to /server/default/deploy, but this does not help. After i put tuxgrh-ds.xml file from a package in the same folder. This is a solution.